# Create 2 side-by-side buttons in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a layout that would like to build the following layout:

```
+-------------------------------+ # wrapped in Scaffold
|           Button 1            |
+-------------------------------+
SizedBox(height: 15)
+-------------------------------+
|           Button 2            |
+-------------------------------+
SizedBox(height: 15)
+-------------------------------+
|           Button 3            |
+-------------------------------+
SizedBox(height: 15)
+-------------+ +---------------+ # wrapped in Wrap
|   Button 4  | |   Button 5    |
+-------------+ +---------------+
Spacer()
```

All the buttons are `ElevatedButton`. Here are the codes (I only show the related Scaffold body part):

```
return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(...), // omitted
    body: SafeArea(
        minimum: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: Center(
            child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                    ElevatedButton(), // Button 1
                    SizedBox(height: 15),
                    ElevatedButton(), // Button 2
                    SizedBox(height: 15),
                    ElevatedButton(), // Button 3
                    SizedBox(height: 15),
                    Wrap(
                        children: [
                            ElevatedButton(style: ButtonStyle(
                                minimumSize: MaterialStateProperty.all<Size>(Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5, 50)),
                            )), // Button 4
                            ElevatedButton(style: ButtonStyle(
                                minimumSize: MaterialStateProperty.all<Size>(Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5, 50)),
                            )), // Button 5
                        ]
                    ),
                ]
            )
        )
```

Currently while using `Wrap`, the layout has become:

```
+-------------------------------+
|           Button 1            |
+-------------------------------+

+-------------------------------+
|           Button 2            |
+-------------------------------+

+-------------------------------+
|           Button 3            |
+-------------------------------+

+-------------+ 
|   Button 4  | 
+-------------+ 
+-------------+ 
|   Button 5  | 
+-------------+ 
Spacer()
```

I tried to replace `Wrap` with `Row`, but it shows `A RenderFlex overflowed by 32 pixels on the right.`. I know it's due to the Safe Area on each side. Is there a way to let the layout calculate the width of each smaller button automatically (and leave a small gap between the Buttons 4 & 5)?

while using `Row`, the layout has become:

```
+-------------------------------+
|           Button 1            |
+-------------------------------+

+-------------------------------+
|           Button 2            |
+-------------------------------+

+-------------------------------+
|           Button 3            |
+-------------------------------+

+---------------+ +---------------+ # wrapped in Row
|   Button 4    | |   Button 5    |
+---------------+ +---------------+ # overflowed on the right by 32px
Spacer()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the last two buttons in the row to have equal width and occupy the full width of the row, you can use `Expanded` widget instead of `minimumSize` property of `ButtonStyle`.

Here's the updated code:

```dart
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: const Text('Button 4'),
      ),
    ),
    const SizedBox(width: 10),
    Expanded(
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {},
        child: const Text('Button 5'),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Expanded widget

```dart
SizedBox(
  height: 50,
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text("4"),
          onPressed: null,
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          child: Text("5"),
          onPressed: null,
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
),
```

Also you should avoid using MediaQuery for response design when ever possible, Use LayoutBuilder if needed.

More about [layout/adaptive-responsive.](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/layout/adaptive-responsive)

Answer (score 1):

Replace your column with this :

```
Column(
                        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {  }, child: null,), // Button 1
                          const SizedBox(height: 15),
                          ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {  }, child: null,), // Button 2
                          const SizedBox(height: 15),
                          ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {  }, child: null,), // Button 3
                          const SizedBox(height: 15),
                          Row(
                              children: [
                                Expanded(
                                  child: ElevatedButton(style: ButtonStyle(
                                    minimumSize: MaterialStateProperty.all<Size>(Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5, 50)),
                                  ), onPressed: () {  }, child: null,),
                                ), //
                                const SizedBox(width: 7),// Button 4
                                Expanded(
                                  child: ElevatedButton(style: ButtonStyle(
                                    minimumSize: MaterialStateProperty.all<Size>(Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5, 50)),
                                  ), onPressed: () {  }, child: null,),
                                ), // Button 5
                              ]
                          ),
                        ]
                    )
```